# trouble updating state in object with componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

So I am in the midst of making a recipe app and have most of it done. I am now looking to integrate an advanced search function so that users can filter what they want to see before hitting the search button. So right now, the part of the state that is relevant to this question looks like this

```
advancedSearchParameters: [

            ]
```

On the entry of a term (sri Lankan) and click of the search button in the search component, advancedSearchParameters in the state will update to have something like this

```
{
                        balanced: false,
                        highProtein: false,
                        highFibre: false,
                        lowFat: false,
                        lowCarb: false,
                        lowSodium: false,
                        vegan: false,
                        vegetarian: false,
                        dairyFree: false,
                        glutenFree: false,
                        lowSugar: false,
                        peanutFree: false,
                        resultNum: 20,
                        searchTerm: ''
                    }
```

This will prompt the component to update with

```
async componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
            if (
                prevState.advancedSearchParameters !== this.advancedSearchParameters &&
                this.state.advancedSearchParameters.searchTerm !== ''
            ) {
                let response = await axios.get(
                    `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${this.state.advancedSearchParameters
                        .searchTerm}&app_id=cf7e1&app_key=946d6fb34df02a86bd47b89433&to=20`
                );
                let data = response.data.hits.map((data) => ({
                    name: data.recipe.label,
                    src: data.recipe.image,
                    source: data.recipe.source,
                    url: data.recipe.url,
                    healthLabels: data.recipe.healthLabels,
                    dietLabels: data.recipe.dietLabels,
                    calories: data.recipe.calories,
                    totalWeight: data.recipe.totalWeight,
                    totalTime: data.recipe.totalTime,
                    totalNutrients: data.recipe.totalNutrients,
                    ingredients: data.recipe.ingredients
                }));
                this.setState({ recipeResults: data });
            }
        }
```

The issue that occurs when i do this is that the API call appears to be sent multiple times, prompting the API to block my request for at least a minute. Can anyone see where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: Instead of using `componentDidUpdate` to fetch async requests, why don't to use click handler, I mean the function you pass to `onClick` prop of you Search button?

Comment: because this is a call to an external API and to my knowledge Api calls that change my state and render new components should be called in componentDidUpdate @rzwnahmd

Answer (score 1):

componentDidUpdate is usually called to handle a change in props, but you're not doing that. You use componentDidUpdate to handle the change of state and then you update the state inside which will retrigger it. You should move that code outside of componenDidUpdate and put it where you update your advancedSearchParameters state, probably in an input.onChange callback.

One more thing, when you do a real time search, you are calling your api at every keystroke. There are 2 ways to deal with that problem.

1. Use axios cancel token, so you can cancel an existing axios request before sending a new one
2. Debounce your axios call, it's a javascript function that will wait for a short delay after the user has typed a key before sending the request

Comment: Sorry mate I dont understand, the componentDidUpdate is triggered when the state changes. when componentDidUpdate is triggered the API call Is sent out. Also the search is not real time as the state change is triggered onClick @HermitCrab

Comment: I thought you were doing a real-time search like google. In your onClick handler, call your API and you will be good. You have to be very cautious when you call setState inside componentDidUpdate, because you risk going into an infinite loop. You won't have this problem if you call your API from onClick

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! All i needed to do was make

prevState.advancedSearchParameters !== this.advancedSearchParameters

to prevState.advancedSearchParameters !== this.state.advancedSearchParameters